# How to create Hybrid application with Angular2.0

Tags: angularjs, angular

My current application is in AngularJS1.4.8 version. I want to create few modules in 2.0. Can I use both version together?

Comment: Refer https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xvBZoFuNq9hsgRhPPZOJC-Z48AHEbIBPlOCBTSD8m0Y/edit It might helpful. It not only provides upgradion steps but also explains how to mix both.

Comment: Link is not working.

Comment: I am using chrome browser. and link was perfectly opened